# How do I go skip an element in a list if all the keys in a dictionary which has a value of a set already has that element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

As the title suggests, if I had a dictionary with keys and values (in which these values are sets) where all of the key's values already have an element from a list, they move on to see if they could add the next element into the set.

For instance,
lst = ['a', 'b', 'v']

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'v']
sample_dct = {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'a'}}
other_dct =  {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'g'}}
test_dct =   {'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a'}}
```

Which these dictionaries would become:

```
sample_dct = {'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a', 'b'}}
other_dct =  {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'g', 'a'}}
test_dct =   {'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a', 'b'}}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'v']

other_dct =  {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'g'}}

j = 0
for i in other_dct:
    while not j == len(lst) - 1:
        if not lst[j] in other_dct[i]:
            x = other_dct[i]
            x.add(lst[j])
            other_dct[i] = x
            break
        else:
            j += 1
    j = 0



print(other_dct)
```

which prints {'test': {'b', 'a'}, 'letter': {'b', 'a'}, 'other': {'a', 'g'}}

I figured out how to only add an element once to the set but I'm still confused on how to only add 'b' if the third key already has 'a'

I'm considerting turning the list into a dictionary similar to the dictionaries it is being added to by turning the keys into values where they're added onto a set like this:
new_dct = {'a': {'test', 'letter', 'other}, 'b': : {'test', 'letter'}, 'v': set()}

but I'm not sure if that will only complicate matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's `all` function to test that all values contain the list item.  If they don't, then the item can be added to all values (as it's a set duplication doesn't really matter) and then return, otherwise move to the next letter in the list.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'v']
sample_dct = {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'a'}}
other_dct = {'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'g'}}
test_dct = {'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a'}}

def add_items(items, dicts_set):
    for item in items:
        if not all((item in val for val in dicts_set.values())):
            for k in dicts_set:
                dicts_set[k].add(item)
            return dicts_set
    return dicts_set
            
print(add_items(lst, sample_dct))
print(add_items(lst, other_dct))
print(add_items(lst, test_dct))
# output:
#{'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a', 'b'}}
#{'test': {'a'}, 'letter': {'a'}, 'other': {'g', 'a'}}
#{'test': {'a', 'b'}, 'letter': {'a', 'b'}, 'other': {'a', 'b'}}
```